# CSV Data Fail to Load in IE but loads in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge in my SharePoint Site Using D3

Tags: csv, d3.js, sharepoint-2013

I have created a SharePoint site.  In the site I’m using D3 to load data from a csv file.  The data loads great in all the browsers except IE (I’m using IE 11).  In the console I’m getting the following errors:

SEC7120: Origin https://intelshare.intelink.gov not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
templates.aspx

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'append' of undefined or null reference
templates.aspx (836,1)

I loaded the CSV file in SharePoint’s assets folder, and I link to the csv inside that folder.  Below is my script I used to load the data.  I don’t know why IE through the above errors and not load like the other browsers.  I appreciate any help/advice you can provide.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var width = 1000, height = 650;

var gallery = d3.select(".gridImage").append("div")
.attr('class',  'imgDiv')
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 650")
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%");

d3.csv('https://intelshare.intelink.gov/sites/nbib/ep/SiteAssets/SitePages/Test%20Page/data.csv', function(error, data){
if (error){
 alert("Data didn't load, Refresh your browser");
 }else{

var container = gallery.selectAll('.imgContainer')
.data(data, function(d) { return d.id; });

container.enter()
.append('div')
.attr('class',function(d) { return  'imgContainer imgContainer' + d.id});


container.selectAll('.picture')
.data(function(d) { return [d]; })
.enter()
.append("a")
.attr('class',function(d) { return  'fancybox-thumb hidden iframe fancybox'})
.attr("rel","fancybox-button")
.attr("href",function(d) {return 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov/sites/nbib/ep/SiteAssets/SitePages/Test%20Page/'+ d.sampleImages})
.attr("data-fancybox",function(d) {return  d.group})
.attr("title", function(d) {return  d.message})
.append('img')
    .attr("class", function(d) { return  "picture picture" + d.id})
.attr('width', "100%")
.attr('height', "auto") 
.attr('src', function(d) { return 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov/sites/nbib/ep/SiteAssets/SitePages/Test%20Page/'+ d.imgsrc; })
}

container.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
    .attr("y", 0 - (300 / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "12px") 
    .style("color", "black")
    .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
    .text(function(d) { return d.imageTitle; });

container.append("a")
.attr("href",function(d) {return 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov/sites/nbib/ep/SiteAssets/SitePages/Test%20Page/'+ d.download;})
.attr("download",function(d) {return d.download;})
.append("rect")  
.attr("class","downLoadBtn")
.style("text-decoration", "none")
.text("Select to download");
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  I change my path to the CSV file from and absolute path to an relative path.  After I made that change my data loads in all browsers. Below is how I modified my path:

Changed from this: "https://intelshare.intelink.gov/sites/nbib/ep/SiteAssets/SitePages/Test%20Page/data.csv"

Changed to this: "../SiteAssets/SitePages/Test%20Page/data.csv"

I hope this helps someone using d3.csv in sharePoint.